# Split incoming XML element into two element notes using XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm posting my first question here, looking for help with converting vendor XML which i have no control over into our system by extending an existing XSD schema (XML>XML).

There are some obvious substitutions that represent like for like tag switches that are easily dealt with. However the hill that I'm dying on at the moment is converting an element tag and it's contents into specific parts (question and answer), whereby the incoming element tag defines the question code, and the value within the tags becomes the answer to that question code.
as follows:

**Incoming XML example (Extract):**

```
<School_lookup_-_CeebCode>233132</School_lookup_-_CeebCode>
```

**needs to become .....new XML example(Extract):**

```
<question>
 <questionCode>CA_LASTSCL</questionCode>
 <answerText>233132</answerText>
</question>
```

**using the following XSD (Extract):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="createRegistration">
   <xs:complexType>
    <xs:all>
     <xs:element ref="questions" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:all>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

<xs:element name="questions">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="question"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

 <xs:element name="question">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="questionCode" minOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element ref="answerText" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I hope that makes sense.
please let me know if anything is unclear

Comment: I don't think XSD alone can do this, but XSLT probably can.

Comment: I'm confused how XSD is being used for any kind of transformation. AFAIK, an XSD describes a single format, it doesn't relate two formats to each other. Can you show us some of the code doing the existing transformation?

Comment: XSD is a declarative notation for defining validity conditions on XML documents.  No XSD schema can by itself restructure your data in the way you describe.  If you are using code auto-generated by some tool that reads a schema, your question is about that tool rather than about XML or about XSD.  If you are using hand-generated code to read your input data, your question is about that code.  If you believe that you are not using any executable code now, but need some in order to transform the input into the form you want, you need to choose a programming language; XSD isn't one.